# Link to share folder using link list not opening in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, hyperlink, links-list

We use link list to create hyperlinks to share folders. I've never had a problem accessing them from Chrome, but with some browsers like Chrome and Mozilla it does nothing. I assume it is how these browsers manage the local folder access. Is there any way around this?

```
file://Server-X/filesharingarea/Blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Chrome extension [IE Tab Multi (Enhance)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab-multi-enhance/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea) did the job for me.

It has the ability to auto-detect URLs so whenever I browse to our SharePoint it emulates Internet Explorer. Finally I can open Office documents directly from Chrome.

You can install [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ie-tab/) for FireFox too.